# Proper way to make SQL queries in code?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server in Visual Studio. I am making a web application.

I have created a database with tables and relationships.

I will need to write functions in C# that will be able to make select, update, delete, queries etc. Does anyone have any insight into a proper way to do this to keep things clean and secure?

By this I mean, how should I be making a connection, how should I return data, deal with failures, etc?

Most tutorials I found do not seem to use best practices.

Comment: I'd do a google search on linq-to-sql.

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM for this?  This is generally considered a 'solved problem'.

Comment: Or you could write stored procs which are better for security (you do not have to allow users direct rights to the tables thus limiting them to only taking teh actions in the proc) and easier to performance tune than ORMS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a good reason you're not using an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)? [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), just to name a few. Unless you're doing some pretty complex SQL statements, an ORM is the logical choice every time. It will handle the connections, provide some level of security (i.e. take steps to avoid SQL injection), as well as just make your code much easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's best practice "du jour" is Entity Framework. Otherwise an ORM such as NHibernate is a good choice as well.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1. Entity Framework, considered best practice in many places.
2. Linq to SQL, again pretty good practice.
3. Other ORM, popular ones are usually good practice
4. Write your own back end interface via stored procedures, not the best practice and definitely not a time saver, but if you aren't familiar with ORM's and its a smaller application, this may be quicker.

**EDIT:**  Best practice isn't to use inline SQL queries, I falsely stated that they open up holes for SQL injections, but if you do them right you can safely do it that way. What I should have said was do not use them if you are trying for best practice. Mainly because down the line, some other programmer may be working on your code a see that you did inline SQL, if they don't know about SQL injection they may make changes that DO allow for a hole. By avoiding inline SQL totally, not only do you avoid making a mistake security wise, but it is somewhat of a defensive programming technique, in the sense that a future programmer is less likely to use inline SQL if you weren't using it in the first place. Hope thats not to confusing :)

Comment: If you properly parametrize your inline SQL queries, these are perfectly **fine** and **DO NOT** open a hole for SQL injection!

Comment: That's correct. I edited my answer to clarify that you can safely use them, but why I don't / never do as best practice.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a relatively small/simple application, maybe you don't need a full-blown ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework.

You can use a Micro ORM instead. These are simpler libraries that don't offer everything that EF and NH can do, but they are all capable of mapping queries to lists of objects.
If your app isn't super complex, maybe that's enough for you.

The most known Micro ORMs for .NET are:

- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) *(made and used by the guys here at Stack Overflow)*
- [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive)
- [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the cleanest way to use tables and relations is to use ObjectDataSource and then Databind to controls and put all your queries into SPs.

Second is to use Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL

put your connection strings into the web.config file, and use a Singleton class to get Connection object.